# Converting C# AES encryption to CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, c#, aes, cryptojs

I have the following code in C#, and I need to replicate the code using CryptoJS.  However I am getting different results.

C#:

```
private static byte[] IV = {58, 88, 123, 111, 98, 109, 112, 54, 35, 13, 63, 53, 234, 55, 44, 41};
private static string key = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

public static string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string encryptedText = "";

    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);

    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        encryptor.Key = keyBytes;
        encryptor.IV = IV;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return encryptedText;
}
```

JS:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create([58, 88, 123, 111, 98, 109, 112, 54, 35, 13, 63, 53, 234, 55, 44, 41]);
var key = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";

function encrypt(clearText) {

    var clearBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(clearText);
    var keyBytes = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);

    var encryptedText = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        clearBytes, 
        keyBytes, 
        { iv: iv }
    ).toString();

    return encryptedText;
}
```

I have tried every variation of this I can seem to think of.  What am I missing in my JS to make it match the C#? The values from calling each of these aren't the same.

(And yes I know that using the same IV isn't a good idea for each request - something I will deal with next).

Comment: Please check the IV. The value 453 seems to be wrong.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [the "The Cipher Output" section of the CryptoJS documentation](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output). `toString()` appears to return "an OpenSSL-compatible format." You may want `cipherText`, or pass `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` to `toString` to match C#. Note this is just from a cursory first reading of the docs.

Comment: The 453 value was a typo.  I changed it to 53.  That wasn't the problem though...  And I tried passing Crypto.enc.Base64 to toString() but that threw an error message...

Comment: `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create()` expects an `ArrayBuffer` or typed array, so `var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(new Uint8Array([58,...,41]).buffer)`. Since key and IV are passed as `WordArray`, `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(...).toString()` returns the Base64 encoded ciphertext, so this should be OK. If you still have problems, please post test data: key and ciphertext.

Comment: Thanks @Topaco - that is what the issue was!!!!!  Thanks so much!